# How to pass an array using AngularJS $resource (performing a DELETE operation)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

I have a WebAPI controller with DELETE method that looks like this

```
public bool Delete([FromBody] List<int> stepIds)
```

I have setup my $resource like this

```
api.mySteps = {delete: $resource('my_URL_Here/api/myController?stepIds=:stepIds,{},{delete:{method:'DELETE', hasBody: true}}) };
```

On my delete button click from UI, I am doing this:

```
    api.mySteps.delete.delete({'stepIds':[1,2,3]}, 
                                 function(res){}, 
                                     function(err){} 
    );
```

With this setup, I am getting NULL in my WebApi Controller.

In the Network tab on my browser console, I see this:

`http://my_URL_Here/api/myController?stepIds=1,2,3`

It's not passed in as an array.

On Fiddler, if I do
`http://my_URL_Here/api/myController?stepIds=[1,2,3]` then it works fine.

How can I pass an array to DELETE?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it to $resource:
For Example

```
'delete': {method: 'DELETE', isArray: true}
```

and here is another example:

```
var deleteRequest = $resource('/api/delete/post', {}, {
    'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
});
deleteRequest.delete({'ids[]':[4,5,6]});
```

then you delete request URL:

```
/api/delete/post?ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3
you get %5B%5D instead of []
```

and if you expect return array instead of an object then you should use

```
'delete': {method: 'DELETE', isArray: true}
```

from looking at your code you are missing the square brackets, so this should fix it:

```
 api.mySteps.delete.delete({'stepIds[]':[1,2,3]}, 
                                 function(res){}, 
                                     function(err){} 
    );
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me. I am still getting `NULL` in my WebApi controller. The data needs to be passed in this format: `http://localhost:5903/api/myController?stepIds=[1,2,3]`. With your way, the data is passed in `http://localhost:5903/api/myController?stepIds[]=1&stepIds[]=2`, which is not expected by the controller